# Using date how to calculate that date today yesterday or one day before etc?

Tags: php

```
$curdate = 2015-13-03 12:06:03
```

Using this `$curdate` how to calculate this date today or yesterday or one day before or two days before etc.. in php

Comment: Look at the functions related to `date()`. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 1):

There's a function called strtotime() in PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

This should be what you`re searching for.

Comment: If you're going to reference PHP.net, use an English version. as in "en" and not "de". not many *"sprachen sie deutsch"* ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36012645/1

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t notice it ;) Edited

Comment: *grazie mille* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtotime.

Example

```
$curdate = strtotime("2015-13-03 12:06:03");

$newdate = strtotime("+1 day",$curdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to do this:

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-12-31 12:06:03');
$date->modify('-1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

but there are multiple roads available.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just assign the time in string to create a date variable.. Checkout this..

```
$curdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",mktime(12,06,03,03,13,2015));
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($curdate)));
$twodaysbefore = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-2 day', strtotime($curdate)));
echo "yesterday: " . $yesterday."-- 2 day before :".$twodaysbefore;
```